# Want to show the average number in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a line chart in Tableau showing sales over time and I have shown the average sales over time using the "Analytics" tab "average line" feature. I would like for the number to show up with the average line. For example, if the average is 800 sales over time, I would like for the number 800 to appear next to the line. Right now the line only says average with no number. Does anyone know a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the guide (look at [this page](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/reference_lines.htm)) you can show the value by using the `label` field in the menu.

Is this your target?

[image]

Comment: This is great! Further, is there a way to limit the amount of decimal points in "value"? Right now it is giving me more than 5 decimal points...

Comment: Not sure but it would probably be possible in the format panel. IMHO it is very detailed so you have to make few tries before finding the correct field https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_worksheet.htm